# Iframe anchors not working in FB tabs

Tags: facebook, resize, anchor

After spending all day trying to make an anchor work in facebook tabs I have given up and ask for help :)

In the following very simple tab http://www.facebook.com/pages/Testing-pages/196886257049573?sk=app_186989884709513 we have an anchor in the end of the page that should bring the user back to the top of the page.

If I leave the iframe scrollbar everything works as expected but if I get rid of the scrollbar with the following js:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId: 'your_app_id',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
});
FB.Canvas.setSize();
};
```

the link stops working and does nothing.
The following issue happens in IE9, FF7 but works well in Safari and Chrome.

I am at a loss and really don't know what to do here.

NOTE1: Tried the following plugin http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

NOTE2: Tried to reload the page through JS but it reloads on the same place where left.

Comment: Have you tried <a target='_top' href='http://www.facebook.com/pages/Testing-pages/196886257049573?sk=app_186989884709513'> on the link, or reloading with top.location.href=http://www.facebook.com/pages/Testing-pages/196886257049573?sk=app_186989884709513

Comment: Or you can use this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/

Comment: target='_top' opens in a new page top.location gives me an error in permissions (cross site security), if I put #name_of_anchor instead of just # it works in IE, so the only one left is Firefox

Comment: If you are already loading the JS SDK, I think FB.Canvas.scrollTo is your best bet.

Comment: DannyKK your answer was correct, that sort out my issue, thank you very much, now I just need to figure out how to set your answer as correct :)

Comment: very helpfull question +1 bounce

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I know this is pretty late, but using jQuery you can bind any `<a href=""></a>` starting with a `#`, finding the top position of that element, then using `FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, position)` to scroll to that element.

http://jsfiddle.net/sluzorz/efyVf/

Edit:

Use `jQuery.offset()` instead.

Comment: Already solved it long time ago, but that is the right answer :)

Comment: Haha, yeah. I was trying to find the solution, might as well post what I came up with :).

Comment: On a side note, you want `.offset` instead to include padding and margins too.